# BaseActivity as Lifecycle Owner for DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-lifecycle

My project structure has a BaseActivity which is extended by multiple child activities, so the structure is like

```
                  BaseActivity
                        ^
                        | 
          -------------------------------
          |             |               |
 ChildActivityA  ChildActivityB  ChildActivityC
```

I am using `DataBinding` with `LiveData`, and hence every time I need to set up the `lifecycleOwner` for the respective binding class i.e (in ChildActivityA)

```
  val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(R.layout.somelayout)
  binding.lifecycleOwner = this@ChildActivityA
```

Now I need to repeat this boilerplate in each `Activity`, so instead I created a helper extension function to replace the above two lines i.e

```
fun <T : ViewDataBinding> BaseActivity.setDataBindingView(layoutId: Int): T {
   val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutId)
   binding.lifecycleOwner = this@BaseActivity
}
```

and then call in my `ChildActivityA` as

```
val binding = setDataBindingView(R.layout.someLayout)
```

As you can see the `binding.lifecycleOwner` is set to `BaseActivity` instead of the actual `ChildActivityA`, now will this cause any trouble? Will the `binding.lifecycleOwner` be still following the lifecycle of `ChildActivityA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this@ChildActivityA` and `this@BaseActivity` refer to the same actual object in memory - there's only one activity object that exists. Therefore they're entirely equivalent.

Comment: Does it mean that even if at compile time it is `this@BaseActivity`, at runtime it would be correctly used as `this@ChildActivityA`,`this@ChildActivityB`, etc depending from which specific child `Activity`  `setDataBindingView(R.layout.someLayout)` is called?

Comment: @iCantC - there is only one `this` object - the actual Activity. TBH, I have no idea why you are using `this@BaseActivity` instead of just `this` in your extension as there's no disambiguation needed in that case.